# CMake syntax: how to negate if(<constant>) and if(<variable|string>)

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

CMake's if command [1] supports several signatures, starting with

```
if(<constant>)
if(<variable|string>)
if(NOT <expression>)
```

How to negate the first two?

If the CMake documentation is correct (which in my experience is far from certain), then my question boils down to:

How to convert a constant, a variable, or a string X into an expression, with the additional requirement that X is to be evaluated as a boolean?

[1] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html

Comment: `if(NOT <constant>)`, `if(NOT <variable|string>)`. Actually, `<expression>` in the third example is just a placeholder for any parameter, which can be passed to `if`.

Comment: if that is the full story, then why not paste it as an answer, which I then quickly accept?

Comment: "<expression> is just a placeholder for any parameter" - a prime example for the many unsaid things that make it so difficult to learn CMake from the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `<expression>` is just a placeholder for **any parameter**, which can be passed to `if`. Even the list of possible `if` constructions is titled as "Possible expressions are".

```
if(NOT <constant>) # Revert 'if(<constant>)'
if(NOT <variable|string>) # Revert 'if(NOT <variable|string>)'
```